# How to change the foreground color in svg to png conversion?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm converting fontawesome 5 *svg* files to *png* using [batik-rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html):

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer-1.10.jar -scriptSecurityOff "svg/" -d "output/" -m image/png -w 16 -h 16
```

How do I change the foreground color of the resulting icons?

EDIT:

According to the [documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html), it's possible to change the background color:

> -bg alpha . red . green . blue : specifies the background fill color as an ARGB quadruple, where each component is an integer in the range 0—255,

But there is no parameter for the foreground.

Comment: The svg file describes the colors that it uses. You can change the SVG to output different colors.

Comment: I have a whole directory with 1200 svg files, changing each svg file would be a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions, in the [batik rasterizer documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) I found the `cssUser` argument:

> -cssUser file|uri : specifies the CSS user stylesheet to use in addition to any other referenced or embedded stylesheets,

With the following argument a CSS can be added to the conversion:

```
-cssUser convert.css
```

Here the css which makes the icons color red:

```
* {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

Here the complete call:

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer-1.10.jar -scriptSecurityOff "svg/" -d "output/" -m image/png -w 16 -h 16 -cssUser convert.css
```